# Fail at controller creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

- Using EF 6.1.1
- (Reinstalled VS2013 + Update) x4
- Happen at each web application project

[image: Error]

Transcript:

*Error*

*There was an error running the selected code generator:*
*'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

Just looked up everywhere on the internet, and nothing works, like:

- Restarting VS
- Reinstalling VS
- Executing Install-Package MvcScaffolding
- Creating another project
- Checking database if exists
- Searching the internet
- Crying
- Now, posting on SO

I'm running out of idea for how to resolve that *Helpless* error

NB1: My database is created using an *.edmx file and SSMS

Thanks for future answers/hints

Answer (score 0):

What DB do you use? I was having similar problems with MySQL, but I was using additional extensions for that DB. (Solved that by reinstalling several times the extension and saving the .edmx every time in source control while working so when it crash can revert it back :) )

Please check the answer of similar question (hope that helps): [Scaffolding controller doesn't work with visual studio 2013 update 3 and 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974218/scaffolding-controller-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013-update-3-and-4)

After having so much issues with .edmx - do not use them... I know is much more code writing but then you can more easily control and modify it when the db design has changed.