# Can ASP.NET MVC + EF scaffolding be used after implementing EntityTypeConfiguration classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-model-builder

**Background**

Visual Studio scaffolding for new ASP.NET MVC Controllers bound to Entity Framework work well when the models use *data annotations* or the direct lines within `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)` to describe their characteristics.

**Issue**

However, in our scenario, the content of `OnModelCreating` is refactored using individual `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` classes. When attempting to create a new Controller via the MVC+EF scaffolding the following pop up error occurs:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'A
>   configuration for type SomeModelClass has already been added. To
>   reference the existing configuration use the `Entity<T>()` or
>   `ComplexType<T>()` methods.'

Is there a fix (ex. custom code or project configuration)?

Comment: which version of visual studio and asp.net MVC you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Here is something that seems to be the same issue as yours :
[Scaffolding controller doesn't work with visual studio 2013 update 3 and 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974218/scaffolding-controller-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013-update-3-and-4)

This is a soluton that seems to work :

> I had added some custom configuration for one of my Model classes to add a relationship using the fluent API. This was specified in my dbContext class in the OnModelCreating override using the following:
>
> modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderConfiguration());
>   Commenting out the above line allowed the Controller scaffolding to run as expected.
>
> VS 2013 update 2 had a problem with this and the scaffolding came up with an unhelpful error with no further information. In installed Update 3 and it gave just enough detail to track down the underlying issue.

Comment: This is an avoidance, not a solution. Disconnecting the generator (i.e. commenting out the `Configurations.Add()` line, prevents the scaffolder from being aware of associated entities attributes, which is exactly what you want the scaffolder to handle.